# Decidability of "Is n divisible with 23?"

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, turing-machines, decidable

I have the following problem:

> Let n be a natural number, n > 10^100. Is n divisible with 23?

**Is this problem semi-decidable or decidable?**

It is possible to create an algorithm to find the answer such that it would always halt. I am pretty confused regarding the difference between semi-decidable and decidable. As far as I understand, a problem is decidable if I can build a Turing machine (algorithm) that would accept the solutions of the problem and otherwise reject. However, if the machine would never halt in the case of inputs that are not solutions, it means that the problem is semi-decidable.

So, I would say that the problem above is decidable but I have no idea if what I said is correct. Can you please help me find out the answer and why? Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that the easiest solution would involve coding an algorithm which does long division.

Comment: @BaconBits No, systematic testing is far easier. (I suspect that this is the easiest way, actually.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. A problem is *decidable* if you can write an algorithm that, for any input, will **always make a decision** eventually. For the problem of "is `n` divisible by 23?", consider the following (bad) algorithm: start with `i = 1`, and check if `23 * i` is less than, greater than, or equal to `n`.

- If it's less than `n`, increment `i`.
- If it's equal to `n`, return `true`.
- If it's greater than `n`, return `false`.

No matter how large `n` is, this algorithm will always spit out an answer eventually, because you can only increment `i` a finite number of times before `23 * i` is greater than `n`. It may take a huge amount of time, but for the purposes of decidability we don't care. So this algorithm always makes a decision; thus, the problem is decidable.

Contrast this with *semi-decidable* problems. These are problems where there exists an algorithm that will always answer `true` if that's the correct answer, but **might run forever if the correct answer is `false`**.

The most famous semi-decidable problem is the Halting Problem: given a program, determine if that program ever stops running. Suppose you try to solve this problem by writing a program that executes its input. If that execution terminates, then you can return `true`: you know the program terminates because you just watched it do so. But if you've waited around for a while and it hasn't terminated, you can never be sure if it won't terminate if you just let it run a little longer, so you just have to wait. Therefore, if the input program doesn't terminate, your program won't either.

Thus, there's an algorithm for the Halting Problem that always returns `true` if the actual answer is true, but runs forever if the actual answer is false. Therefore, the Halting Problem is semi-decidable.

Answer (score 3):

```
return (n % 23 == 0)
```

Does this not count as an algorithm? Seems decidable to me.

Please see the [answer by Hermann Döppes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51226314/3033441) you don't want to assume the computability of modulus.

Comment: I think the point is that n is a number that is too large for division, which is what the modulo operator is doing.  Keep in mind that IEEE 754 is not accurate enough to  represent the least significant digits.

Comment: But why does IEEE 754 have anything to do with decidability? Eventually, the number would be larger than what we could possibly store, but that does not stop the algorithm from being decidable. As long as the number has finite length, the turing machine will stop and reach a decision.

Comment: Well, but you might still be missing the point. If I cannot assume the decidability of divisibility why should I assume the computability of the remainder?

Comment: I agree that my answer assumes the computability of the modulus operation (which is easy to demonstrate). I am updating my answer to reflect this fact. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is decidable. To give a more basic argument than Lakshay Garg:

- You can enumerate all the numbers k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …
- You can multiply those successively by 23.
- Now comes the interesting step:

  - If 23*k is smaller than n, try the next k.
  - If 23*k = n, then n is divisible by 23. DONE.
  - If 23*k is larger than n, we can stop, as with any further k we will only surpass n further. If we found no k = n/23 by that point, there is none and n is *not* divisible by 23. DONE.

As 23*n is larger than n, we will reach the last step at the latest when k = n, which means this procedure terminates.